# using Object... in codenameone

Tags: android, object, mobile

I'm using Codenameone to develop application in mobile. I want to create a method to show an error message on Screen. But I got an error:

This is my code

public class Common {

```
public static boolean checkNullOrEmpty(String value){
    return !(value != null && !value.equals(""));
}
public static void showMessage(String title,String msgID, Object... params){

    String result = String.format(msgID, params);        
    Dialog.show(title, result, "OK", "Cancel");
}
```

}

And this is the way I call that method:

Common.showMessage("Error", "Item %s ; Item %s","01","02");

This is error message:

error: cannot find symbol
  String result = String.format(msgID, params);
  symbol:   method format(String,Object[])
  location: class String

Can anybody help me? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`String.format` isn't supported by the Codename One subset of the Java API. You should be able to use something like `StringUtil.replaceAll` etc. to replace entries e.g. for this:

```
Common.showMessage("Error", "Item {0} ; Item {1}","01","02");
```

You should be able to do something like this:

```
String result = msgID;
for(int iter = 0 ; iter < params.length ; iter++) {
    result = StringUtil.replaceAll(result, "{" + iter + "}", params[iter]);
}
```